# How to remove items from Ilist

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an IList , I also have a method which checks if the item is already in list and if it is I need it to be deleted/ removed and add again.

```
 private PurchaseItemViewModel CheckSessionPurchaseItemViewModel(long purchaseLevelId)
        {
            bool itemFound = false;
            PurchaseItemViewModel purItem = new  PurchaseItemViewModel();

            foreach (var item in UserSession.UserDataPurchaseItems)
            {
                if (item.PurchaseLevelId == purchaseLevelId)
                {
                    itemFound = true;
                    purItem.Note = item.Note;
                    purItem.PurchaseAmount = item.PurchaseAmount;
                    purItem.PurchaseLevelId = item.PurchaseLevelId;
                }
            }

            if (itemFound)
            {
                return purItem;
            }

            return null;
    }
```

If it the above method finds the purchase item then it returns an object else null.

```
IList<PurchaseItemViewModel> purchaseSessionList = UserSession.UserDataPurchaseItems;
PurchaseItemViewModel pItem = CheckSessionPurchaseItemViewModel(levelId);
if(pItem != null)
{
    purchaseSessionList.Remove(item);
}
```

So the issue is with the below line it is not removing the item , it does not even error.

```
**purchaseSessionList.Remove(item);**
```

Comment: Please post a sample that reproduces the issue. `Remove` will remove the first instance of the item found, based on the object's implementation of `IComparable<T>` (or `IComparable`). Note that the default implementation for a class is a reference comparison. How are you detecting if the item exists? What is the relationship between `pItem` and `item` (and what is `item` defined as)?

Comment: item is PurhcaseItemViewModel in  a list of PurchaseItemViewModel

Comment: And how does `PurchaseItemViewModel` implement `IComparable<T>`? Where is the code that detects that an item already exists?

Comment: Have you tried changing to to List instead of IList and also then when you are pulling items from UserSession then call ToList().

Comment: Most likeley your viewmodel does not implement `IComparable<T>`. Thus the `Remove`-method has no way to indicate if two items are equal. As it can´t find any equal item, it won´t delete any item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code for removing:

```
if(pItem != null) purchaseSessionList.Remove( purchaseSessionList.SingleOrDefault( s => s.PurchaseLevelId== levelId) );
```

IMHO you don't need to create pItem, would be enough to return false or true or item primary key.